# Computing a numerical Hessian matrix and 2 questions on SAS v8 finite difference approximations for the entries

Tags: numerical-methods

I am investigating the maximum value for $h$ for a multivariate function:

$h = f(x_i)$ for $x=1 \ldots n$

and using the gradient method:

$x_i = x_0 + \lambda \nabla x_i$

with $\lambda$ a small scalar to update $x_i$. However the function is converging way too slow and I need to speed up its convergence using Newton's method with a numerical Hessian matrix.

[SAS v8 Finite Differences](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/ormp/chap5/sect28.htm) states that for central difference approximations that:

$g_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \frac{f(x+h_i e_i) - f(x-h_i e_i)}{2h_i}$

for 1st order derivatives and that:

$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,^2_i} = \frac{-f(x+2h_i e_i) + 16f(x+h_i e_i) - 30f(x) + 16f(x-h_i e_i) - f(x- 2h_i e_i)}{12h\,^2_i}$

and

$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = \frac{f(x+h_i e_i + h_j e_j) - f(x+h_i e_i - h_j e_j) - f(x -h_i e_i + h_j e_j) + f(x- h_i e_i - h_j e_j)}{4h_i h_j}$

for numerical approximation of the second derivatives.

I am not sure what $e_i$ in the first partial derivative above, as I am simply using $\triangle x = h_i e_i$, a small value compared to $x$, and finding the first partial derivatives that way.

My question is this, assuming that I set $h_i e_i = h_j e_j$ for the second derivatives, then the second one for $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial y_i}$ becomes:

$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = \frac{f(x+ 2h_i e_i) - 2f(x) + f(x- 2h_i e_i)}{4h^2_i}$

Is this correct? Can I safely use this an an approximation for the numerical Hessian matrix entries?

Some one in another thread [Summary of Optimization Methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189637/summary-of-optimization-methods/192400#192400) stated that

$H \approx J^T \, J$ where $J$ is the Jacobian. Will this work instead?

Comment: Are you still interested in the answer? By $e_i$ is meant an $n$-dimensional vector with 1 at position $i$ and zeros elsewhere. Thus $h_ie_i + h_je_j$ is a $n$-dimensional vector with $h_i$ at position $i$ and $h_j$ at position $j$ (and 0's elsewhere)